# Install Go from source to custom prefix

Tags: go

I have a Go installation in /usr, which is old (yum).  If I download the source from the Golang site and run the all.bash, the binaries and libraries are installed in the downloaded dir.

With a usual Makefile, it's easy to set PREFIX, can this be done in the all.bash file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "install" it anywhere as long as you have `GOPATH` set and add `$GOROOT/bin` to your path.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/src/go/bin"
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'd rather do it system wide in /usr.

Comment: You can't without a lot of work, the easiest way is to install it in say `/usr/src/go` and edit /etc/profile.d/99-go.sh and add the path there. If you want the really complex way, look at how Arch packages it https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/go/go-hg/PKGBUILD

Comment: @jdborg I've had mine in `/usr/src/go` (well the path doesn't matter really) and updated my `$PATH` to point to it for the last 60 months or so, never had problems with it.